# Eclipse: replace tokens before deploying to WTP server

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

in order to support different staging environments I extracted the database access to the maven pom.xml file which replaces the tokens on a build (and can be overridden from the command line). Works fine from command line on our CI server.

Now I am usually developing in eclipse but I can't figure out how to tell eclipse to do the same (ie replace tokens) to have a valid database connection - I am using the standard eclipse server feature.

On the other hand when running it as a maven build from within build I was not able to deploy it to the eclipse server so that I can debug my application.

Any advice on how to accomplish replacing tokens from eclipse so I can debug?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the m2e plugin active so Eclipse knows about your Maven things?

Comment: Yes, maven dependency management is also active and is working.

Comment: I am having the same problem.  The token replacement works, placing the modified resource in the m2e-wtp/web-resources folder, but those resources are never deployed to the wtpwebapps folder of the server, instead, the resources prior to the token replacement are deployed.

Comment: JFYI, I ended up using only maven. Deploying to my application server using maven and remote connecting to it for debugging. Works quite well but takes more time to deploy than the eclipse WTP feature.